# How do I raw URL encode/decode in JavaScript and Ruby to get the same values in both?

Tags: javascript, ruby, encoding

I am working on a web application where I have to encode and decode a string at the JavaScript side and Ruby backend of the code. the only problem is that the escape methods for JavaScript and Ruby have a small difference. in JavaScript the `" "` is treated as `"%20"` but in ruby the `" "` is encoded to `"+"`.

Any way to solve this? Another Ruby method to encode a string in raw URL encode?

After some Selenium testing I noticed that for some reason the `URI.unescape` mixes up between the `"£"` and the `"?"`. If I use `encodeURIComponent("£");` in JavaScript and then `URI.unescape("%C2%A3")` in Ruby which is the value we get when we encode the `"£"` sign, I get the `"?"` sign returned. Any solution?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use

```
URI.escape(foo, Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))
```

in ruby, and

```
encodeURIComponent(foo);
```

in javascript

Both these will behave equally and encode space as %20.

Comment: thanks, but for some reason the "URI.escape(foo, Regexp.new([^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))" isn't working for me, it gives an error and the page doesn't load when it calls it. i have require 'uri' at the top of the class. thanks

Comment: just got it working, me being the idiot that i am was having the Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]") in the unescape as well... that what happens when u have been looking at code for 10 hrs straight. thanks very much @sean it all works properly now

Comment: HI again, after some selenium testing i noticed that for some reason the URI.unescape mixes up between the "£" and the "?" , in my test i if i  encodeURIComponent("£"); in java script and then URI.unescape("%C2%A3") which is the value we get when we encode the "£" sign, i get a return of the "?" sign, any work around? thanks

Comment: `URI.escape` is obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: @MichieldeMare could you consider adding an answer with a non-deprecated method? None of the Ruby built in methods I've tried (ie. CGI.escape or URI.encode_www_form_component) appear to produce identical results to JavaScript.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore the function got removed in Ruby 3.0.0

Comment: A non-deprecated solution that worked for my use was: CGI.escape(foo).gsub('+', ' '). Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623632/586033

Answer (score 5):

[URI.escape](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-escape) was deprecated, an alternative is [ERB::Util.url_encode](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB/Util.html#method-c-url_encode).

```
ERB::Util.url_encode(foo)
```

If you are using it inside an `.erb` file you can do:

```
u(foo)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
require "uri";
puts URI.escape "1 2;", Regexp.new("[^0-9a-z\\-_.!~*'()]", "i");
```