# Ruby equivalent to JavaScript’s encodeURIComponent that produces identical output?

Tags: javascript, ruby, escaping, encode

Hi is there an equivalent ruby method to JavaScript `encodeURIComponent` method? i am using the `URI.unescape(str)` but it recognizes the  `"£"` (after `encodeURIComponent` it becomes `"%C2%A3"`) as a `"?"` sign. any solution's? thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
URI.escape(foo, Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))
```

found here: [How do I raw URL encode/decode in JavaScript and Ruby to get the same values in both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834034/how-do-i-raw-url-encode-decode-in-javascript-and-ruby-to-get-the-same-values-in-b)

URI.escape is obslete since last I posted. As per suggested comment, now use: `ERB::Util.url_encode` or `CGI.escape`

Comment: lets say i have a str = "£" i use encodeURIComponent(str) in javascript, but when i use URI.unescape(str) in ruby and that string comes back as a str = "?". so there are differences

Comment: `URI.escape` is obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: @MichieldeMare, what should be used?

Comment: @BrendonMuir I'm not the one you asked, but to answer your question, `ERB::Util.url_encode` or `CGI.escape` although neither solution is perfect unfortunately.

Answer (score 12):

`CGI.escape` should escape correctly, except that spaces are escaped as `+`.

Note that `URI.escape` has been deprecated in Ruby 1.9.2...

There is a long discussion [on ruby-core](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/vframe.rb/ruby/ruby-core/29293?29269-30059) for those interested.

Answer (score 12):

I think the simplest way is [`URI.encode_www_form_component`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form_component).

Answer (score -1):

[URI.escape](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI/Escape.html)

Comment: lets say i have a str = "£" i use encodeURIComponent(str) in javascript, but when i use URI.unescape(str) in ruby and that string comes back as a str = "?". so there are differences.