# How to correclty assign string which contains spaces to data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I've got stuck at one issue that, I am getting string from server side as **one bottle only**. I am assigning that string to data attribute like

```
var uom = serverSideValue // Contains ["one bottle only"]
<div class="uomClass" data-uom="+ JSON.stringify(uom) +"></div>
```

But when I inspect that element in developer tools, it is appearing like

```
data-uom="["one" only"]
```

If not JSON.stringify

```
data-uom="one" only
```

When I am trying to access uom, like below

```
$('.uomClass').data('uom')
```

above line of code giving result as only **one** instead of **one water bottle**

What I am doing wrong here. I am dynamically constructing the uom html above. Please guide me through the right way. Thank you.

Comment: The issue is because the JSON being output also contains `"` characters which is conflicting with the quotes around the attributes in your HTML. You need to HTMLEncode the JSON before storing it in the attribute

Comment: You could start with:  `data-uom='+ JSON.stringify(uom) + ' ` - but if you have `["there's one bottle only"]` it will fall over with the same issue.

Comment: The first block with two lines of code suggests that the first line is *javascript*, while the second line looks like *HTML* with some javascript inserted in the wrong way. The two languages cannot be mixed in that way. Please make a good distinction between what is actually javascript and what is actuallty HTML.

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan your suggestion helped me to solved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the issue by taking **Rory McCrossan** suggestion in the comments section below the question. I've used [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

**HTML Code**

```
var uom = serverSideValue // Contains ["one bottle only"]
<div class="uomClass" data-uom="+ encodeURIComponent(uom) +"></div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
var $uom = decodeURIComponent($('.uomClass').data('uom'))
```

Now I am getting the correct results. Thank you **Rory McCrossan** for your suggestion.

Comment: In order to do the encoding in ruby I needed to run `ERB::Util.url_encode(string)`. Got the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858432.