# javascript .data() cuts the string content by whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

So, I have this problem where I have a backwards-button in a webapplication. This is the javascript-code for the button:

```
function getPrevFunction()
{
    localDBSelect("prevViews", function (prevViews)
    {
        if (prevViews)
        {
            var prevViewObject = $.parseJSON(prevViews);
            var prevViewArray = prevViewObject['funcObjects'];
            if (prevViewArray.length > 1)
            {
                var prevArrayIndex = prevViewArray.length - 2;
                var actArrayIndex = prevViewArray.length - 1;
                var prevFuncObject = prevViewArray[prevArrayIndex];
                var prevFunc = prevFuncObject['function'];
                var prevConfig = prevFuncObject['config'];
                var inData = prevFuncObject['inData'];
                prevViewArray.splice(actArrayIndex, 1);

                if (inData !== "")
                {
                    if (prevFunc !== "getGuiSiteList")
                    {
                        inData = "<div data-param=" + JSON.stringify(inData) + ">";
                    }
                    $('#fieldcontain')[prevFunc](inData, prevConfig);
                }
                else {
                    $('#fieldcontain')[prevFunc](prevConfig);
                }

                if (prevViewArray.length === 1)
                {
                    setVisibilityForBackBtn(false); //If last..
                }

                prevViewObject['funcObjects'] = prevViewArray;
                localDBInsert("prevViews", JSON.stringify(prevViewObject));
            }
            else {
                setVisibilityForBackBtn(false);
            }
            $('#subcontainer').html("");
            if(!$('#fieldcontain').is(":visible"))
            {
                $('#fieldcontain').show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is that I don't always get the entire content of the json-object. Eg; the json, at the beginning it looks like this:
 `input = {site: "GAV", location: "EG", set: "INVENTORY", binnum: "B01 T09"}`

but after I have tried to fetch the json that is being passed as a data/attribute with an html-element like so: 
`var input = $(inData).data("param");`

the value I recieve looks as follows: 
`input = "{"site":"GAV","location":"EG","set":"INVENTORY","binnum":"B01"`

As you can se it has by some reason cut off all the characters after the whitespace, despite nothing happens between the fact that the last functions is added to the list, and that function is then called again, too be able to go backwards in the application.

I do realize that my explanation is messy and probably hard to understand, but this is the best that I can explain it. 
I can provide more code if necessary.

So, I do need the entire json for the getPrevFunction (it is passed as "prevViews")

Comment: Create element using jQuery i.e. `inData = $('<div />').data('param', inData);`

Comment: Use **encodeURIComponent()** and **decodeURIComponent()** `inData = "<div data-param=" + encodeURIComponent(inData) + ">"` and to fetch the data use decodeURIComponent(). Please refer this question from this link [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925098/how-to-correclty-assign-string-which-contains-spaces-to-data-attribute/48925751#48925751)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()` like below

**Setting the data**

```
inData = "<div data-param=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(inData)) + ">";
```

**Getting the data**

```
var input = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($(testDv).data('param')));
```

Now there will be no cuttings in the object due to whitespace.

Comment: Hrm, I still don't seem to get this to work. When I'm doing as suggested the google chrome developer tool console throws this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Function.parseJSON (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (plugins.js:1471)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at init.each (jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)
    at init.$.fn.getItemList (plugins.js:1458)

Any ideas to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Vic it should work, did you debug the code in developer tools?

Comment: Hey @Vic with a little change in my answer, it will work, find the answer in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Javascript_Lover/d721v43u/8/)

Comment: @Vic I am glad to hear that, can you mark the answer as accepted/approved answer. Thank you...