# URI encoding not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On a rails app, I need to parse uris

```
a = 'some file name.txt'
URI(URI.encode(a)) # works

b = 'some filename with :colon in it.txt'
URI(URI.encode(b)) # fails URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):
```

How can I safely pass a file name to URI that contains special characters? Why doesn't encode work on colon?

Answer (score 12):

[`URI.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-escape) (or `encode`) takes an optional second parameter. It's a Regexp matching all symbols that should be escaped. To escape all non-word characters you could use:

```
URI.encode('some filename with :colon in it.txt', /\W/)
#=> "some%20filename%20with%20%3Acolon%20in%20it%2Etxt"
```

There are two predefined regular expressions for `encode`:

```
URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED  #=> "\\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\\d"
URI::PATTERN::RESERVED    #=> ";/?:@&=+$,\\[\\]"
```

Comment: A more general approach would be to do `URI.encode('some filename with :colon in it.txt', Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))`. See here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834034/how-do-i-raw-url-encode-decode-in-javascript-and-ruby-to-get-the-same-values-in.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'uri'

url = "file1:abc.txt"
p URI.encode_www_form_component url

--output:--
"file1%3Aabc.txt"


p URI(URI.encode_www_form_component url)

--output:--
#<URI::Generic:0x000001008abf28 URL:file1%3Aabc.txt>


p URI(URI.encode url, ":")

--output:--
#<URI::Generic:0x000001008abcd0 URL:file1%3Aabc.txt>
```

> Why doesn't encode work on colon?

Because encode/escape is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Addressable::URI::encode`](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/Addressable/URI.html#encode-class_method)

```
require "addressable/uri"

a = 'some file name.txt'
Addressable::URI.encode(Addressable::URI.encode(a))
# => "some%2520file%2520name.txt"

b = 'some filename with :colon in it.txt'
Addressable::URI.encode(Addressable::URI.encode(b)) 
# => "some%2520filename%2520with%2520:colon%2520in%2520it.txt"
```

Comment: %2520 is a double encoding. %20 is the encoding for a space. Then if you encode the string "%20", the encoding for a "%" sign is %25, giving you "%25" + "20" or "%2520". You don't want to double encode strings. Also you need to: gem install addressable.  But also note that the colon was not encoded in the output.

Comment: @7stud You are right.. But this gem is URI s replacement currently..And I just tried to show OP what was not being achievable by URI can be done using this  `Addressable`... :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the empty space preceding the colon, `'lol :lol.txt'` don't work, but `'lol:lol.txt'` works.
Maybe you could replace the spaces for something else.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to escape special character from the given string. It is best to use

```
esc_uri=URI.escape("String with special character")
```

The result string is URI escaped string and safe to pass it to URI.
Refer [URI::Escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html) for how to use URI  escape. Hope this helps.